# Shuffle a list of numbers, character and symbols

Tags: python, variables, methods

I was in the process of creating a simple program to generate a password with a 'List' consisting of numbers, symbols, and characters. In the process, I wanted to randomize and shuffle them.
I used the random.shuffle method to shuffle the list. My question (Sorry, very new to Python) - why cannot we store the outcome of a shuffle activity into a variable.
Giving an example here.

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
shufflefinal = random.shuffle(mylist)
```

(Why cannot we store the random.shuffle(mylist) into a variable shufflefinal)
What is the rule here ? I understand how to get the outcome but wanted to understand the difference and the logic on why this cannot be stored and retrieved through a variable .

Your insight would be valuable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation on [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle):

> Shuffle the sequence x **in place**.

This means the list provided as argument is mutated. It follows the same principle as `sort`, which is also in-place.

If you want to leave the original list unmodified, then create a copy:

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
shufflefinal = mylist[:]  # Get a shallow copy
random.shuffle(shufflefinal)  # Shuffle the copy
```

The above documentation mentions another way:

> To shuffle an immutable sequence and return a new shuffled list, use `sample(x, k=len(x))` instead.

So in your case:

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
shufflefinal = random.sample(mylist, k=len(mylist))
```

Comment: Thanks trincot. I have added another question to make my problem statement better. Sorry for the previous incomplete problem statement. I am very new to StackOverflow posting questions. Pardon me.

Answer (score 3):

random.shuffle() function modifies the original list. This function returns None so it can't store modified list to shuffllefinal var.

```
mylist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
print("Before shuffle: ", mylist)
random.shuffle(mylist)
print("After shuffle: ", mylist)
```