# Python - Random.shuffle returns nonetype instead of list whereas random.choice returns str or int

Tags: python, methods

In the code shown in the snapshot - if you see line 708 (random.choice) . I have assigned this method to a variable to capture the randomized elements. This works fine because line 711 prints the type str which is as expected.
b) Whereas if you see line 726(random.shuffle) , I have used another method called a  random.shuffle which shuffles the list and tried to assign it to a variable but returns nonetype

Ques 1 : Why is that line 711 returns 'str' as expected whereas 727 returns nonetype . Both are using methods. One for str whereas other for list
Ques 2 - And how to change the nonetype to List type  ? Reference line 726 , 727 ?

Simple way to ask the question  - Random.shuffle returns nonetype instead of "list" type whereas random.choice returns str or int type accordingly. Why there is a difference in behaviors of two different methods . What is the rule and the logic behind the rule?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4rLs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Ss1.jpg)

Comment: Add your code and output here instead of a screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot resolution is so low you can't read it. Also please paste code as mentioned above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why-does-random-shuffle-return-none](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17649875/18127542)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to change the nonetype to List type

You don't. Realise what it means for a method to apply an [**in place** algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm): it means that the result is available in the variable that you have provided as argument. There is no need to assign it, as you already have it: the variable you passed as argument has the result. See also the answers to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71100194/5459839).

> Why there is a difference in behaviors of two different methods. What is the rule and the logic behind the rule?

There is indeed a logic as to why these methods were designed like that:

If the method intends to *mutate* an argument, then it should not return anything other than `None`

So in this particular case we have `random.choice`. This method is not about mutating a list. It is a "read-only" method, that just chooses an element from a given list. There is no mutation going on, and no new object is created. It merely uses what is already there. So this is the perfect situation for *returning* the result.

On the other hand we have `random.shuffle`. This method suggests (by its name) that it will rearrange the given list (randomly): that is a *mutation*. The same can be said about `sort`: it also mutates the list on which that method is called. So here the principle is to *not* return anything. If the name of the method were `random.shuffled`, then it would have been a different story: *that* name suggests you would get a variant of the given list that is rearranged; in other words: a *new* list would be made. In that case, the original list would not be mutated, and it would be appropriate for the new list to be the returned value. This method does not exist, but the same idea does exist for sorting: `sorted` returns a new list.

I hope this explains why the language designers have designed these methods to work like that.

Answer (score 0):

**random.shuffle()** returns **None** since it shuffles the list in place, it does not return a random value from the list.